# Flex Mobile Project, How can I write by a dynamically TextArea to a .txt file?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, file-io, flex-mobile

I have some dynamic textArea in a flex mobile project, created in this way:

```
var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
textArea.id = "txtCreaTaskAnalysis" + contatoreNumeroTextAreaCreaTaskAnalysis;
textArea.left = 235;
textArea.right = 90;
textArea.horizontalCenter = 85;
textArea.height = 200;
contatoreNumeroTextAreaCreaTaskAnalysis += 1;
this.gruppoCreaTaskAnalysis0.addElement(textArea);
```

When a save button is clicked, I want to save them text in a .txt file.
I know how to create and write in a flex mobile project, but I can't find the correct way to select the textAreas..
How can I do that?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fe4.html#WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fe2

textArea.selectRange(startHere,endHere);

Should do the trick.

If you're referring to retrieving whatever text is in the TextArea you can simply access textArea.text, if you're looking for something else I don't understand.

Comment: I want to retrieve the text, but I have more than one textArea, so I tried to put them in an array, and after write in file in this way:    fs.open(creaFileTesti,FileMode.APPEND);
for(var i:Number = 0;i<=contatoreNumeroTextAreaCreaTaskAnalysis;i++)       fs.writeUTFBytes(arrayTextAreaCreaTaskAnalysis[i].text +';');
fs.close();   But it doesn't work..